# How to call object inside ActiveModel:Serializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, active-model-serializers

I am using Active Model Serializer gem to serialize json object.

I would like to reveal field A if the value from field B match to the condition.

But field A is a private information. So, previous developer write a custom function call “authenticated_belongs_to” and uses it in ActiveModel:Serializer

The problem is I can’t directly call object to get field B

```
authenticated_belongs_to :item, serializer: ItemOwnerSerializer if object.B
```

above code give me an error because undefined object

I also tried to get object value through a method

```
authenticated_belongs_to :item, serializer: ItemOwnerSerializer if condition_method

def condition_method
  object.B
end
```

But above code doesn’t work because it gives me an error unknowed condition_method

I have tried the whole day to find out the solution but I just watse my time. Could anyone help?

Comment: Try `authenticated_belongs_to :item, serializer: ItemOwnerSerializer, if: :condition_method`

Comment: can you share the function code of `authenticated_belongs_to`

Answer (score 0):

Accoriding to [ActiveModel::Serializer documentation](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/v0.10.6/docs/general/serializers.md#attribute):

> An `if` or `unless` option can make an attribute conditional. It takes a
>   symbol of a method name on the serializer, or a lambda literal.

So you should change the code to:

```
authenticated_belongs_to :item, serializer: ItemOwnerSerializer if :condition_method
```